# How does the memory mechanism (reading and writing) work in a neural Turing machine?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, math, memory, neural-turing-machine

In neural Turing machine (NTM), reading memory is represented as

\begin{align} 
r_t \leftarrow \sum\limits_i^R w_t(i) \mathcal{M}_t(i) \tag{2}
\end{align}

and writing to memory is represented as

Step1: Erase

\begin{align} 
\mathcal{M}_t^{erased}(i) \leftarrow \mathcal{M}_{t-1}(i)[\mathbf{1} - w_t(i) e_t ] \tag{3}
\end{align}

Step2: Add

\begin{align} 
\mathcal{M}_t(i) \leftarrow \mathcal{M}_t^{erased}(i) + w_t(i) a_t \tag{4}
\end{align}

In the reading mechanism, if we take this example values and applied to the above formula, instead of a vector, we get a scalar of value 2.

```
M_t =[[1,0,1,0],
      [0,1,0,0],
      [1,1,1,0]]

w_t = [1,1,1]
```

The same thing happens in writing as well; here we take the dot product of two vectors,  $w_t(i) e_t$,  with a scalar value as output. According to paper, unless $w_t$ or $e_t$ are zeros, it will erase **all values** in the memory matrix.

My own idea about NTM memory was that it uses the weights to find the indices or rows inside the memory matrix corresponding to a certain task.

How does the memory in NTM work?

How a memory for a particular task is stored, that is, is it stored row-wise or it's stored in the whole matrix?